# AngularJS Sortable, can't get the Reciever List (ul) ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am relatively new to AngularJS and there is some issues that I am facing. Sorry if my question is stupid.

I have UL lists populated from Angular and I CAN get the ID of the Dragged item,the Index of that Item, the ID of the List it is been dragged **From**, but NOT the ID of the List it is been Dragged **TO**. It keeps returning me **undefined** or **null** all the time.

Believe me I've tried lots of code variations. Any ideas would be highly appreciated

INDEX.html

```
<ul id="sortable{$ review[0].progressFlag $}" ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="review" class="connectedSortable apps-container">
    <li id="item{$ item.id $}" ng-repeat="item in review">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <p><b>{$ item.name $}</b></p>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

APP.js

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
    items:'li',
    start: function(event, ui) {
        item = ui.item;
        console.log(item.attr('id'));      // Dragged Item ID - Works
        console.log(ui.item.index());      // Dragged Item Index - Works
        console.log(ui.item.parent().attr('id'));   // The List ID Item being dragged From - Works
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {          
        item = ui.item;
        console.log(ui.item);
        console.log(ui.item.parent().attr('id')); // The List ID Item being dragged TO = UNDEFINED
    },
    connectWith: ".apps-container",
};
```